# Xcode plist validation script

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Following problem: in a project with several targets (schemes) occur from time to time wrong configs. They won't be recognized by Xcode, so I wrote a Swift script to check them. The path is given by command line parameter.

Now I need to integrate this script into Xcode, so it's run everytime I compile one of the targets.

My idea was to use the run script. But there are 2 problems.

1. How do I get the path? The path can be "calculated" if the target/scheme name is known.
2. How do a raise an exception in Xcode, so it stops building when there is an error and shows my error?

Comment: if you return from a script build phase it will kill the build, if you want to construct it you will have to look at all of the env vars that are available at build, which you can do by expanding a build log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is easy. By using PRODUCT_NAME I get the name of the scheme/target and more I don't need. By using PROJECT_DIR I'm able to build a absolute path and it's perfect.